# Database that allows full text search in O(1)

Tags: database, data-structures, data-science, full-text-search, corpus

I have a database of documents where searching quickly for keywords and patterns would be very useful to have.

I know of "Burrows–Wheeler transform"/FM-index. I wonder if there are any programs or database programs based on BWT or similar methods in order to search a corpus in O(1) and hopefully more advantages.

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting question. Thanks for asking.

Comment: On a related note there is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_to_rank, and I do not not the actual complexity, but it requires offline (out-of-core?) learning.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great book by Witten/Moffat/Bell (1994) *Managing Gigabytes*; this describes in detail everything you need to know about indexing and retrieval. I think their sourcecode is also available, or has been made available in an information retrieval library.

However, it doesn't include the [Burrows-Wheeler transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform), as that was only invented in the same year.